# VBA Copy Destination but as values

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2013

I'm trying to transfer data from one document to a different document using "Copy Destination" as I want to avoid using the clipboard but I want it to stop taking the formatting with it...

```
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim FoundLocationSheet As Boolean
Dim n As Long
Dim AllSheet As Worksheet
Set AllSheet = Sheets("Main")

'Transfer data
For n = 1 To AllSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If AllSheet.Cells(n, 1) = "TiTle" Then
        With Sheets(AllSheet.Cells(n - 1, 1).Value)
            AllSheet.Cells(n, 1).CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)
        End With
    End If
Next n
```

The macro could potentially pull data from `A20:L40` and put it into `A15:L35`...

I'd been trying lots of different things with `AllSheet.Cells(n, 1).CurrentRegion.Copy Destination:=.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)` but can't work out how to make it work...

The size of the sheet means clearing formats takes way too long :/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to *avoid* the clipboard and only copy Values, you can use assignment to the `Value` property instead of `Range.Copy`

Something like this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim FoundLocationSheet As Boolean
    Dim n As Long
    Dim rSource As Range
    Dim rDest As Range
    Dim AllSheet As Worksheet

    Set AllSheet = Sheets("Main")

    'Transfer data
    For n = 1 To AllSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If AllSheet.Cells(n, 1) = "TiTle" Then
            With Worksheets(AllSheet.Cells(n - 1, 1).Value)
                ' Reference the range to be copied
                Set rSource = AllSheet.Cells(n, 1).CurrentRegion
                ' Reference the Top Left cell of the destination range
                ' and resize to match source range
                Set rDest = _
                  .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0) _
                  .Resize(rSource.Rows.Count, rSource.Columns.Count)
                ' Copy values
                rDest.Value = rSource.Value
            End With
        End If
    Next n
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the data to any array and then from array to the destination. The code to do this is short and surprisingly efficient. Note: The source must have more than one cell.

```
' Create dynamic array
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim rg As Range


Set rg = AllSheet.Cells(n, 1).CurrentRegion
' Read values to array
arr = rg.Value

' Write the values back sheet
.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Value = arr
```